# How can I implement technically the described proposed client/server model

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, client-server

I want to implement a simple client/server model in my application. Client will send a file to server and server will convert it and sent back converted file. But problem is that How can I implement the scenario so that server tell the client periodically about the status of conversion.
In my case it is difficult that client asks the server about status update.

**Part of the image in red is asked. How can I implement it in C# code.**

[image: Image of [proposed model]

Comment: You may implement a [WCF Duplex Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx). However, that is not a trivial task. A solution where the client cyclically polls the service is much easier to implement. You don't need clients to register themselves for receiving status updates from the service. The service does not need to manage registered clients.

Comment: Just in case the server is able to deliver already converted parts of the file, you may even combine polling for status and data. You might just cyclically request the currently available part of the result data until you've got it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement WCF duplex service would be better. using duplex WCF service  we can check status.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731184(v=vs.110).aspx